# telnet client not responding after recv()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, telnet

i am just starting to learn how to code socket but having problem i can't solve.

so i was trying to create a telnet client and i have succeeded to receive the first message from the server but after this receive line, my program kind of stuck and won't do anything else. not even a simple printf line.

thanks in advance,
Ricky

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error_msg(char msg[256]){
    printf("error at %s\n", msg);
}

void main(){
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char buffer[2048], server_reply[2048];
    printf("trying to connect to []...\n");

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd<0) error_msg("socket");

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");   
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(23);

    int conn = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    if(conn<0) error_msg("connect");
    printf("connected to server\n");

    bzero(server_reply, 2048);
    bzero(buffer, 2048);

    while(1){
        int n_recv = recv(sockfd , server_reply , sizeof(server_reply) , 0);
        if(n_recv > 0){

            printf("%s", server_reply);
            sleep(1);

            scanf("%s" , buffer);
            int n_send = send(sockfd , buffer , sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if(n_send < 0) printf("send error, server is not responding...\n");     
        }
        if(n_recv < 0) printf("recv error, server is not responding...\n");
    }

    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: you're printing when it is > 0, < 0, but what about when it IS 0?  Put an fprintf(STDERR (that's important) before and after calling recv and in the one after, what exactly is the return code and errno set to?  Also, how do you know if you successfully received a message from the server?

Comment: If n_recv is 0, you would be in a busy loop - nothing would be printed.  Also, are you sure any data is being received.  Have you tried monitoring the traffic with something like Wireshark or tcpdump?

Comment: i have checked. the return value is 24, not 0. with wireshark, i lost response from the server right after recv() and before send().

Comment: Don't do `send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)` instead you should say `send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)`. Also the telnet protocol has some initialization which must be obey.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what the return value is, it seems likely the remote side has closed the connection:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

```
The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.
```

Look at my comment on your question and post that data and I should be able to help more.

Comment: thanks for answering. i added some printf to check the return value and it's not 0. it's 24 (the size of server's response line i suppose?).
i also checked with wireshark, apparently the server has stopped replying my connection after the recv() and before send()

Comment: Also you can't just printf the data you get from recv -- there's nothing to guarantee it's null-terminated.